# Sales Product Block Disappeared In Magento

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.7

I don't know what happened. All the sudden I looked at my home-page and the std-saleproduct block doesn't load in the right side of the body website. My website is http://yourvaporizers.com

You can look at the theme how it is suppose to look here -- http://magentodemo.creative-d2.de/exdress/

Not sure what's causing it or all the sudden why it would happen. I downloaded some extensions but right away it didn't do anything to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try reindexing & clear cache - then re-login.
and also check your xml in which that block in call.

Comment: I did all that, I think when I flushed the CSS/JS cache is when it happened, not sure though. I uploaded the xml files I have on my computer already which didn't do anything. I'll check for more tho.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was Use **Flat Catalog Product** and I had set it to **YES**, it is now changed to **NO** .

I had set it to YES cause I read it helps reduce server load in backend.